# REST API versioning. What to include in a new version?

Tags: rest, api, versioning, endpoint

So let's say that I have two endpoints:

- example.com/v1/send
- example.com/v1/read

and now I have to change something in */send* without losing backward compatibility. So I'm creating:

- example.com/**v2**/send

But what should I do then? Do I need to create *example.com/**v2**/read* which will be doing same as /**v1**? And let's imagine that there are lots of controllers with hundreds of endpoints. Will I be creating a new version like that with changing every small endpoint? Or should my frontend use API like that?

- example.com/**v1**/send
- example.com/**v2**/read

What is the best practice?

Comment: What you are suggesting is a good enough approach, but depend on the case. For bigger scale - you may want to explore API Gateways and/or Service Registries - some call them "edge" service. The main idea is that your "edge service" will route requests to the appropriate endpoint, without altering clients. Clients will always call example.com/send, but your edge service will route those requests to v1/send or v2/send depending on some criteria. You can use this to roll out changes to just a targeted group of clients etc. Just google for this strategy and you will see a lot of examples.

Answer (score 1):

Over the time new endpoints may be included, some endpoints may be removed, the model may change, etc. That what versioning is for: *track the changes*.

It's likely that you will support both version 1 and 2 for a certain period, but you hardly will support both versions forever. At some point you may drop version 1, and want to keep only version 2 fully up and running.

So, consider the new version of the API as an API that can be used independently from the previous versions. In other words, a particular client should target one version of the API instead of multiple. And, of course, it's desirable to have backwards compatibility if possible.

---

*In good time:* Instead of adding the version in the URL, have you considered a media type to handle the versioning?

For instance, have a look at the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/). All requests are handled by a default version of the API, but the target version can be defined (and the clients are encouraged to define the target version) in the `Accept` header, using a media type:

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json
```

Comment: It's better to use media types to deal with new versions of specific endpoints instead of a whole new url structure.

Comment: @Evert Definitely using media type is a much better way to handle that.